# Database Space Used Decreased after Index Rebuild (Ola Script)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index-tuning, ola-hallengren, database-size

I have rebuilt some indexes which were highly fragmented. After the index rebuild I am seeing my database space used reduced by almost 50% (from 77gb to 33 gb)

Is that normal behavior? I dont have auto shrink turned on - did I lose data?

Note: *space used* decreased *in* my database file; the actual physical size of my database file is unchanged.

Command used to calculate the space used:

```
SELECT sum(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT))/128.0 as Space_Used_MB
```

Results of `select @@version`

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU11) (KB4077063) - 12.0.5579.0 (X64)

Rebuild of indexes performed using Ola Hallengren's script. Parameters used:

```
Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
FragmentationMedium='INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE 
',
FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', 
FragmentationLevel1 = 5, FragmentationLevel2 = 30, FillFactor=80, 
UpdateStatistics = 'ALL', OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y', LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

Comment: Can you see any DBCC Shrink commands in the SQL ERRORLOG?

Comment: My bad .. I read it `auto shrink turned on` but not the `dont` part :-) I have deleted my answer.

Comment: I restored a production database to a test server. There is no job that is running....When I compare the space i see the discrepancy

Comment: This server was used as a log shipped server prior...Thats the only unusual thing i can relate to

Comment: Were you previously using a fillfactor on your indexes of less than 80?

Comment: The database where the rebuilt operation was done uses a default fill factor of 0

Comment: Can you check (ask around or dev team)  if data was truncated before you did a rebuild ? thats the only bit left to check since you check most of the stuff.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that since the tables were heavily fragmented the rebuilt freed up some space used...I restored it from a back up so there is no chance of truncation

Comment: still no report from the Errorlog or default trace :)

Comment: No errors reported...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not lose data with index maintenance / rebuilds. As your data is fragmented, the data would be spread over multiple leaf pages in the clustered / nonclustered indexes  as data is deleted / updated over time leaving empty space in the page position where it was originally. Reorganizing / rebuilding the index recovers the space by reordering the data in the pages and releasing the space back to the database for future use.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite common behavior. You are reclaiming unused space by reordering pages in the leaf level.

Just don't shrink your datafile unless it's critical - you'll probably need that space in the future. You are just wasting time, fragmenting (again) the database and locking tables.

Comment: All my big indexes were 99% fragmented... it released 50 % used space after rebuilt... just worried whether there was any data loss or not